# What is the different between these blocks of code?

Tags: python

I want to make a game in Python using socket, and I want my server to check if there are 5 clients listening to the server, and if yes, start the game.

But I'm not sure how to do that, there is two different ways to do what I want, but I want to know, Is there a different in performance or something else ? Will it work the same ?

```
while True:
    self.conn, addr = server.accept()
    self.players.append(self.conn)
    if len(self.players) == 5:
        # self.start_game()
```

```
while True:
    self.conn, addr = server.accept()
    self.players.append(self.conn)
    if len(self.players) == 5:
        break
# self.start_game()
```

Is there any different with the memory, performance or something else ?

Comment: 1st code block is an infinite loop. 2nd code block will exit the loop if `self.players`'s length is 5.

Comment: @Ch3steR But it will stop when the function is called, right ?

Comment: Nope it wouldn't stop. It starts `self.start_game()` once `self.start_game()` ends loop again resumes it will be in infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block of code will continue to run forever, even if that condition is met, since the condition to the loop is alway `True`.

The second block with `break` out of the loop if that condition is met, thus preventing the loop from running forever.

Regardless of what `self.start_game()` does, your `while` loop will run infinitely because that line doesn't change the condition that causes the loop to keep running.

### Code clean up recommendation:

```
while len(self.players) < 5:
    self.conn, addr = server.accept()
    self.players.append(self.conn)
```

This prevents the loop from running again once the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

You want the 2nd version.

The 1st loops forever, since `start_game` probably does not reset
to an empty list of players.

There is no need for the while True.
This would be a clearer way to express the loop condition:

```
while len(self.players) < 5:
    self.conn, addr = server.accept()
    self.players.append(self.conn)
```

It shows that you intend for length to count from 0 .. 4 and still run the body.
Once the length hits the desired value of 5,
there is no longer a need to await further connections.
There is no infinite looping ambiguity about
"what if there were already half a dozen players?"

Comment: `while not len(self.players) == 5:`. I think this is better, because I want only 5 players.

Comment: `while not len(self.players) == 5` is actually worse because if there is some weird bug that cause the `len` of players to be more, the loop will run infinitely again...

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first case. The programme will never end. If start_game ends the programme will start again with appending the players. In the second case, the python program will end when start_game() ends.